# Can I have different warning levels for different folders in Xcode?

Tags: xcode

I compile my Xcode projects with very high warnings settings.  Sometimes, I have to use third-party frameworks that are distributed as source (rather than as a framework).  These frameworks often throw a lot of warnings.

Is there a way to turn off warnings for these folders?  I want the stricter level for my own code, but don't care if third-party code violates my warnings level.

Basically, I don't want to see 67 warnings every time I build.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for this:

`#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wdeprecated-declarations"`

Flags can be found here: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.4.6/gcc/Warning-Options.html

Just replace the -W... with whatever you want to ignore.

Comment: Thanks, I used the `-w` flag, coupled with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6057192/how-do-you-set-file-specific-build-settings-in-xcode-4 to hide spurious warnings in third-party code.