# How do you set file-specific build settings in XCode 4?

Tags: xcode4, settings

In xcode 3 it was possible to configure specific option for building every single file of a project, like for example disabling specific warnings, thumb code generation and so on.
In xcode 4 such feature is not available, or at least not in an intuitive way. This is however supported, at least as a backward compatibility feature, in projects imported from xcode 3.x.

Does anyone knows a way to specify those settings without having to open the project back in older xcode or creating a project for every single file?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Select the project in the navigator, then select the target from the list. Select the Build Phases tab, then expand the Compile Sources phase. The Compiler Flags column is where you specify per-file compiler flags.

Comment: So simple but so hidden. Thank you. Saved days of my life.

Comment: I used this to hide warnings on a third-party .m file by setting the compiler flags to: `-w`.

Comment: how do you find the name of the warning to supress and what is the format of the option to suppress it

Comment: This kind of small things are driving me nuts all the time I have to use IDEs.

Comment: this tab seems to be hidden by default. it does seem to appear if a project is included in a workspace though... no idea how to make it appear consistently :/

Comment: @jheriko I haven't encountered the problem you described. The Build Phases tab is available as soon as you select your build target from the Targets list (after selecting the project), regardless of whether or not the project is contained in a workspace.